# Running Doom 1 in a Linux virtual machine with 8 bit color

Tags: linux, virtual-machine, resolution, colors, emulator

I'm trying to compile and run the original Doom 1 game in a Linux based virtual machine. I've managed to get the source code compiled (from here: https://github.com/id-Software/DOOM) but I can't run the produced executable as the game only supports 8 bit color resolution.

How can I create a Linux based virtual machine that supports an 8 bit resolution? Or can I use something instead of a VM to get the 8 bit color mode required?

Ideally, I'd like a VM that can run the compiled Doom executable but can also edit and compile changes to the source code.

Comment: AFAIK there's no easy way to get 8 bpp (paletted) support on a modern X server with 24/32 bpp (true color). It might be easier to patch the source code to use true color; I have done this with some other X legacy application.